# for loop iterator suddenly changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my method, its just a nested loop:

```
IEnumerator startNewRound()
{
    string st = "آبپتثجچحخدذرضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی";
    for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; i < st.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int z = j + 1; z < st.Length; z++)
            {
                if (z > st.Length) continue;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
                Debug.Log("I = " + i + " J = " + j + " Z= " + z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

suddenly inside the loop program freezes for some seconds and, 'j' counter changes and every thing blows up!
here is my Log:

[image]

I cant understand what is wrong!

Comment: I can't see your log as image. Post it as text

Comment: As a note a debug log inside the second loop but outside the third would probably have helped you debug the issue. Or indeed just using a debugger and stepping through. You'd have quickly seen j getting to a value that shouldn't have been allowed and probably then noticed the problem that JamieC described in his answer. Debugging is your friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your second nested loop, you mistakenly use `i` instead of `j` as the loop control variable:

```
for (int j = i + 1; i < st.Length; j++)
```

Should be

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < st.Length; j++)
```

Why does this cause a problem? Lets look at the pertinent part of the utput:

> I = 0 J = 24 Z= 25
>   I = 0 J = 24 Z= 26
>   I = 0 J = 25 Z= 26
>   I = 0 J = 2147483647 Z= -2147483648
>   I = 0 J = 2147483647 Z= -2147483647
>   I = 0 J = 2147483647 Z= -2147483646

At the point that your code hits I=0, J=25 & z=26 (which is one less than the length of `st`) the following happens:

- `z` gets incremented to 27
- The test in the 3rd loop checks `z < st.Length` and thus ends that loop
- `j` gets incremented to `26`
- The third loop initialises `z` to `j+1` (27)
- The third loop evaluates `z < st.Length` - false. Exit the loop without ever entering it to output anything
- The second loop evaluates `i < st.Length` - true and enters the loop.
- After that loop `j` is incremented
- continue ad infinitum until integer overflow

Comment: While that is true, wouldn't `j` still be initialized to `i+1` and never be that negative value. In other words, your answer is true, but does it answer the question?

Comment: the negative value is likely due to overflow of the int.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen You might be right, I dont know - we cant see what else is going on. But id bet it has something to do with that loop control var!

Comment: @Stucky: ALmost certainly true, this answer could do with actually explaining why the code does what it does though. Good answers explain not just what to change but why the change is necessary.

Comment: @Chris but we cant see enough of the rest of the code to know what is going on. Theres no explnation possible at present, but as I said above id bet its related to the loop control var!

Comment: oh wait...maybe it does.

Comment: @Jamiec: you absolutely can see the main problem. Basically the third loop never does anything if j > st.length (since z will be too). So the second loop keeps incrementing j until finally it gets to max value and z will then overflow and finally the third loop will do something. The only thing I can't work out is why j is -2147483648 rather than 2147483647. I suspect this may be due to the code given not exactly matching the output we are shown.

Comment: @Chris yup. Updated answer. Its not so easy to describe. I think you might have done a better job than me

Comment: @Jamiec: I think your answer describes it admirably! I started writing my own answer trying to explain it in full and I was very glad to see you looked like you were going to update because my answer reads horribly (the added detail for the answer made it super messy).

Comment: I leave my previous comment to avoid creating gaps in the comment thread here but you're absolutely right of course.